# How to represent products made of products in MySQL? Nested set or anything else?

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I'm creating a web application to manage a fast-food store and I need to cover this situation: the store has products made of other products and single products.

Example: I sell 1 burger (made of bread, beef and cheese) and 1 can of soda.

I need to discount 1 bread, 200gr of beef, 50gr of cheese and 1 can of soda from the stock. I'm solving this using tables for:

1) products (burger, can of soda and any other "sellable" product) which also stores the amount in stock,

2) ingredients (bread, beef, cheese, etc.) which also stores the amount in stock,

3) ingredients_products (associative). Also stores the quantity of ingredient in product.

The problem comes when I need to register a "purchase". Because in a single purchase I can have single products (10 cans of soda) and ingredients (10kg cheese) and I need to identify if each item is a product or an ingredient to increment the amount in stock.

Looks like trees or nested set won't help because one product can be used in several products, for example: cheese can be used in pizzas, burgers and other meals.

Any suggestion to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If the product represent like your idea, it would be very complicated for both business logic and front end represent. I would prefer to keep it simple.

Every selling item would be represent as a individual item (unique SKU).

e.g.:

- Cheese, it would have 500g, 1000g and 2000g packing. So in single purchase you may deduct your stock of 5 x 2000g of Cheese. so the product of "2000g Cheese" deducted 5.

  present in database table

  **Cheese 500g**

  - product_name: Cheese 500g
  - sku: cheese_500g
  - qty: 20

  **Cheese 1000g**

  - product_name: Cheese 1000g
  - sku: cheese_1000g
  - qty: 10
- Can of Soda it much more easily. They are prepack, so in your system, you will a single record of product like this

  - product_name: Soda 330ml
  - sku: soda_330ml
  - qty: 500
- a Pizza

  - product_name: Pizza
  - sku: pizza
  - qty: 5